# MediaPlayer - ¿Necesito crear un buffer? ¿Cómo lo hago?

Tags: java, android

Mi problema es que muchas veces no conecta con la radio, sobre todo  si estoy con 4g.
He visto que en aplicaciones con video crean un archivo de buffer y después lo reproducen.

¿Sería ésta la mejor opción?
¿Pueden orientarme para llegar al resultado deseado?

Aquí el código con el que estoy trabajando:

```
 package com.gep.desarrollos.miradio;

  import android.media.AudioManager;
  import android.media.MediaPlayer;
  import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
  import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public final String url = "http://www.radionoventa.com.ar:8000/Noventa_en_vivo.mp3";
MediaPlayer player;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 // Inicializo el objeto MediaPlayer
    initializeMediaPlayer();

    // Inicio el streaming de radio
    startPlaying();

    isPlaying();
}

private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
    player = new MediaPlayer();

    player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
        }
    });
}

public void startPlaying() {

    try {

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        //        "Conectando con la radio, espere unos segundos...",
        //        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        player.reset();
        player.setDataSource(url);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                player.start();

            }
        });

        player.prepareAsync();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException
            | IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error al conectar con la radio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
private void isPlaying(){
    if (!player.isPlaying()) {

          startPlaying();

    }

}

public void Pausa(View view) {


    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.pause();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pausa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startPlaying();


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Te llega a onBufferingUpdate a 100%? o bien puede ser tema de timeouts https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html

Comment: no me está mostrando el log, no se por qué?

Comment: Mirate este tutorial que eseñan como usar mediaplayer https://www.sitepoint.com/develop-music-streaming-android-app/

Comment: Por lo visto MediaPlayer no está 100% pensado por streaming de audio Google recomienda usar ExoPlayer https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edición**

Buscando como solventar los cortes de audio he encontrado la recomendación de Google en usar [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) para consumir broadcast streaming de audio, ofrece una mayor configuración...

Aquí el [Github de ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

#### Otras librerías

[RadioPlayService](https://github.com/iammert/RadioPlayerService)

[OpenPlayer Android](https://github.com/audionowdigital/openplayer-android)

**Media Player**

Acabo de hacer una prueba y veo que el `MediaPlayer` no pasa por el `onBufferingUpdate` no ser si es porque es un streaming de radio, su configuración etc... en cambio si se prueba con un mp3 entero si que pasa por el `onBufferingUpdate`

- Cuando se corta el streaming se recibe un

> E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0) o bien un waring W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)

```
com.webserveis.app.testaudiostream E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
com.webserveis.app.testaudiostream E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
com.webserveis.app.testaudiostream E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
com.webserveis.app.testaudiostream E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
com.webserveis.app.testaudiostream E/MediaPlayer: Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0x0, mCurrentState=1
com.webserveis.app.testaudiostream E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
com.webserveis.app.testaudiostream E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
```

El ejemplo tiene algunos bugs, pero es funcional:

```
package com.webserveis.app.testaudiostream;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;

/*
https://www.sitepoint.com/develop-music-streaming-android-app/
 */

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Button btn;
    private boolean playON;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private boolean initialStage = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.audioPlayPause);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if (!playON) {
                    btn.setText("Pause Streaming");

                    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                        if (initialStage) {
                            //String sourceAudio = "https://www.ssaurel.com/tmp/mymusic.mp3"; //normal
                            String sourceAudio = "http://www.radionoventa.com.ar:8000/Noventa_en_vivo.mp3"; //streaming
                            try {
                                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(sourceAudio);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();


                        } else {

                            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                                Log.i(TAG, "continue playing ");
                            }
                        }

                        playON = true;

                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "onClick: No internet connection");
                    }

                } else {
                    btn.setText("Launch Streaming");

                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                    }

                    playON = false;
                }
            }
        });


    }

    private void togglePlayPause() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.w(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "stop mediaplayer: ");
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            Log.w(TAG, "remove mediaplayer: ");
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }

    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate() called with: mediaPlayer = [" + mediaPlayer + "], i = [" + i + "]");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCompletion() called with: mediaPlayer = [" + mediaPlayer + "]");

        Log.e(TAG, "SE HA CORTADO EL STREAMING o buffer vacio");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onError() called with: mediaPlayer = [" + mediaPlayer + "], i = [" + i + "], i1 = [" + i1 + "]");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPrepared() called with: mediaPlayer = [" + mediaPlayer + "]");
        mediaPlayer.start();
        initialStage = false;

    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSeekComplete() called with: mediaPlayer = [" + mediaPlayer + "]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias @Webserveis! no pude hacer andar el ejemplo, apenas toco btn se cierra la app y el debuger no me marca el error. una pregunta  el exoplayer funciona bien?

Comment: pues no lo he probado con exoplayer, el botón reset si que anda muy mal, pero lo otro te debería funcionar bien. he quitado lo de reset del ejemplo