# Android se detiene al pulsar varias veces un boton

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando una app para escuchar radios en streaming pero si pulso 3 veces el botón, esta se detiene.
otro problema es que me gustaria que este un segundo en buferring antes que empieze a reproducir para evitar que empiece, se pare y continue.
Log Cat:

```
10-02 21:22:15.160 20358-20358/com.david.animefm2 V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
10-02 21:22:15.160 20358-20358/com.david.animefm2 V/MediaPlayer: notify(100, -38, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
10-02 21:22:15.265 20358-20358/com.david.animefm2 D/ViewRootImpl@e6a08af[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-02 21:22:15.323 20358-20358/com.david.animefm2 D/ViewRootImpl@e6a08af[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-02 21:22:15.324 20358-20358/com.david.animefm2 V/MediaPlayer: setVideoSurfaceTexture
10-02 21:22:15.324 20358-20358/com.david.animefm2 V/MediaPlayer: prepare
10-02 21:22:15.324 20358-20358/com.david.animefm2 E/MediaPlayer: prepareAsync called in state 0, mPlayer(0x0)
10-02 21:22:15.325 20358-20358/com.david.animefm2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-02 21:22:15.325 20358-20358/com.david.animefm2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.david.animefm2, PID: 20358
                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                        at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1408)
                                                                        at com.david.animefm2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:72)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11180)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Este es mi código:

```
//Boton Reproducir y pausa
    Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.START);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isPlay ==0) {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();
                //start.setText("PAUSE");
                isPlay = 1;
            } else if (isPlay == 1) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                //start.setText("START");
                isPlay = 2;
            }else if (isPlay == 2){
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();
                //start.setText("PAUSE");
                isPlay = 1;
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"First select a radio station", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Djdadi43!, es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y además obtienes tu primera medalla. Además es **muy importante revisar [ask]** que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas. En cuanto a tu pregunta si eres desarrollador android es importante el uso de LogCat, ya que tu problema puede tener infinidad de causas.

Comment: ya he actualizado la pregunta con el logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso el error es un `IllegalStateException` al tratar de usar el método `.prepare()` :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.david.animefm2, PID: 20358
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException at
>   android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method) at
>   android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1408) at
>   com.david.animefm2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:72)

En este caso, no debes usar `prepare()` y posteriormente `start()` o viceversa:

```
 mediaPlayer.prepare();
 mediaPlayer.start();
```

Debes usar el listener [OnPreparedListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html) para determinar cuando el `MediaPlayer` esta listo para reproducción y de esta forma llamar el método `start()` para iniciar la reproducción:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        //Inicia reproducción.
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

En cuanto a lo que realizas:

> si pulso 3 veces el botón, esta se detiene.

debes validar si el MediaPlayer esta reproduciendo si es así debes detener la reproducción, cargar el nuevo url y realizar el procedimiento anterior, preparar y reproducir:

```
 if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();     
 }
```

Si necesitas implementar buffering revisa las opciones que sugiere @WebServeis:

[MediaPlayer - ¿Necesito crear un buffer? ¿Cómo lo hago?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/69236/mediaplayer-necesito-crear-un-buffer-c%C3%B3mo-lo-hago/69328#69328)